# Custom Config Section in app.config in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, app-config

I added custom config section in web.config MVC Web Project and it is working fine. I did the same in app.config under Windows Service Project and it is throwing error.

```
The type initializer for 'Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory' threw an exception
```

But on removing the custom config section, it is working fine without errors.

```
<configSections>
<section name="RegisterSchedule" type="Sample.Common.CustomConfig.RegisterScheduleConfig, Sample.Common.CustomConfig" />
```

```
  <RegisterSchedule>
    <Schedules>
      <Schedule Name="TestSchedule1" Value="test" IsEnabled="true" />
      <Schedule Name="TestSchedule2" Value="123" IsEnabled="true" />
    </Schedules>
 </RegisterSchedule>
```

Comment: What was the inner exception and stack trace. If you analyze that, you could get a lot of meaning insight into this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked when i moved `<configSections>` to the top of the `app.config` next to `configuration`.